# sql count group by from row

Tags: sql, count, group-by, row

I have a table

```
Sport    Name   gender
----------------------
tennis   John     M
football David    M
football Jane     F
football Brad     M
```

the result I wish is like

```
Count Sport Gender
1      Tennis  M
0      tennis  F
2      football M
1      football F
```

So far I could get is like

```
Count Sport Gender
4      Tennis  M
4      tennis  F
4      football M
4      football F
```

or I can count only1 condition like tennis and Male.

I have read the aggregate function but I still can't make it. I can't think of solution to count it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, `CROSS JOIN` + `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `COUNT`

```
SELECT a.sport,
       b.gender,
       Count(c.sport) AS count
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT sport
        FROM   yourtable) a
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'M' AS Gender
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'F') b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable c
                    ON a.sport = c.sport
                       AND b.gender = c.gender
GROUP  BY a.sport,
          b.gender
```

**Demo:**

*Table schema & Data*

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
  (
     Sport  VARCHAR(50),
     NAME   VARCHAR(50),
     gender CHAR(1)
  );

INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('tennis','John','M' );
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('football','David','M' );
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('football','Jane','F' );
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES ('football','Brad','M' );
```

**Result**

```
╔══════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║  sport   ║ gender ║ count ║
╠══════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║ football ║ M      ║     2 ║
║ football ║ F      ║     1 ║
║ tennis   ║ M      ║     1 ║
║ tennis   ║ F      ║     0 ║
╚══════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

The key here is that since you want to be able to get 0 counts, you need to `CROSS JOIN` to get all of the possible combinations, even when no rows exist in your table that match that criteria (for example, no rows with a female tennis player).